# Disk2vhd - netbook cloning

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, disk2vhd

I recently tried cloning (p2v) a netbook (Compaq 110 Mini) using SysInternals Disk2VHD tool (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx)

When I created a VMC in VPC (Virtual PC) on my Windows 7 Ultimate laptop the VPC of my netbook wouldn't boot beyond the initial BIOS test. All I got was a black screen.

Does anyone have any advice on what to try to debug this  ?

Answer (score 1):

There is new version (1.3) out. That version solves problem with booting of some machines. Just retry whole process with new disk2vhd.

> This update to Disk2vhd makes more Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 VHDs bootable by updating their MBR and boot sectors to be compatible with Hyper-V and Virtual PC and by installing the Intelide driver if it it’s not already installed. It also optimizes image creation by not copying paging and hibernation files.

Comment: funnily enough I just noticed this about 15 minutes ago, just after I posted the question I looked again at the page and saw the updated version number, checked out the main page for the update history and saw the comment you made. It's currently re-working under my desk, I'll try the VPC in about 14 hours when I get home, and update this question.

Answer (score -1):

I have had too many problems with disk2vhd. Instead I used virtualbox with vm_converter. Very good results. Here is the instruction page for that : [How to Convert a Physical Windows XP Machine to a VM (P2V) for Use in VirtualBox.](https://pjsquared.com/2009/07/08/how-to-convert-a-physical-winxp-machine-to-a-vm-p2v-for-use-in-virtualbox/)